# How to show customized icon for secondary form when opened from Main Form

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I have two forms, Main Window and Secondary Window.
When I click Open from a menu in the Main Window, it should open the Secondary Window. By default the secundary window should open in maximized state. And when it opens in maximized state, I want it to show a custom icon that I have setup for it.
But instead, it shows the windows icon.
What should I do so that it shows my custom icon when I open it from the Main Window?

I have tried setting this.icon = new System.Drawing.icon(stream) as well but of no use.

```
public SecondaryWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(currentDirectory + @"\images_UDp_icon.ico");
}

private void secondarytest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;            
    this.ShowIcon = true;
}
```

It shows the default windows icon when opened from Main Window in maximized state. But when i minimize it and then maximize it then it shows custom icon.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. Do you mean you want the secundary window to show a custom icon, but only in certain condition ?

Comment: no, it should show custom icon on all conditions. But what is happening is when opened for first time, it shows windows icon and when minimized, then it shows custom icon.

Comment: Set the `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` in the designer: it's useless if set in `Form.Load`. `this.ShowIcon = true;` is the default, you can remove it. Test with `this.Icon = new Icon(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "images_UDp_icon.ico"));` If the Icon is not set/changed, then your Icon is not a valid one.

Comment: It did not work...added the line in designer file but it did not open in maximized state also.

Comment: This, of course, doesn't usually happen. Thus, there something else in your code that modifies that Icon or the Form is recreated at some point. Make a test using a brand new Form where you just set the Icon in the constructor.